# >java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData;

Tags: java, android

I Don't Why I'm getting error :-

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData;
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.(Fragment.java:254)
> at com.plz.djaman.allsaver.settingFrag.(settingFrag.java:18)
> at com.plz.djaman.allsaver.homeActivity$100000000.onNavigationItemSelected(homeActivity.java:36)
> at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:204)
> at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
> at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
> at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
> at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView$1.onClick(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:115)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
> at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.plz.djaman.allsaver-Ajcrql0ZP_Kz1oCg-PDv2A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.plz.djaman.allsaver-Ajcrql0ZP_Kz1oCg-PDv2A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)

**homeActivity.java**

```
package com.plz.djaman.allsaver;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class homeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment fragment = null;
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.home:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            fragment = new homeFrag();
                            break;
                        case R.id.download:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            fragment = new downloadFrag();
                            break;
                        case R.id.setting:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            fragment = new settingFrag();
                            break;

                    }
                    
                    return loadFragment(fragment);
                    
                    
                }
                private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
                    //switching fragment 
                    if (fragment != null) {
                        getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                            .commit();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
    
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
package com.plz.djaman.allsaver;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class downloadFrag extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //just change the fragment_dashboard
        //with the fragment you want to inflate
        //like if the class is HomeFragment it should have R.layout.home_fragment
        //if it is DashboardFragment it should have R.layout.fragment_dashboard
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.download_frag, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

like this " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError " error  , It's basically a version-import problem ,You should try to modify the version that your Gradle imports jar